# AutoCompleteTextView within popup in MainActivity

Tags: java, android, popup

In MainActivity I have popup with AutoCompleteTextView and it works. I can even do some staff with this (e.g.textView.setText("New")). But I am concerned about adapter because after clicking TextView nothing happen (no list and keyboard).

I think that problem is in line:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String (customView.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, countryNameList);
```

Especially in first parameter - context. I don't know what should I put there.
My code:

```
public void steptwo() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_observedproperty,null);

        mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                customView,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        String[] countryNameList = {"India", "China", "Australia", "New Zealand", "England", "Pakistan"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(customView.getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, countryNameList);
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        textView.setText("New");
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21){
            mPopupWindow.setElevation(5.0f);
        }

        mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(mRelativeLayout, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
    }
```

Comment: Try customView.getActivity() @here  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(customView.getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, countryNameList);

Comment: customView doesn't have method getActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the `PopupWindow` focusable. To allow the `AutoCompleteTextView` to open the keyboard immediately, set the `SoftInputMode` for the `PopupWindow` as `SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE`.

```
public void steptwo() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_observedproperty,null);

        mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                customView,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        String[] countryNameList = {"India", "China", "Australia", "New Zealand", "England", "Pakistan"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(customView.getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, countryNameList);
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        textView.setText("New");
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);
        textView.setThreshold(1);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21){
            mPopupWindow.setElevation(5.0f);
        }
        mPopupWindow.setFocusable(true);

        mPopupWindow.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(mRelativeLayout, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
    }
```

Comment: Keyboard shows now. But when I starting typing app crashed and I get: `2019-07-11 15:05:07.837 15843-15843/com.example.myapplication E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
2019-07-11 15:05:19.790 15843-15843/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 15843
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@943a1d5 is not valid; is your activity running?`

Comment: I think you might be trying to `finish` your activity while your `PopupWindow` is up.

Comment: Btw, you can't start your `PopupWindow` in `onCreate`, your activity needs to be running for the `PopupWindow` to get a window that it can attach itself to.

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I didnt start popup in `onCreate`. I face another weird problem: when I typing some letter than don't fit my countryNameList option I dont get an error-it's ok; but when my typed letter fits any option for example "Ne" (to get New Zeland) app crashed with same error as above. Do you have similar behaviour?

Comment: I didn't get any errors. Post your entire activity code and I might be able to give you an idea as to what's going wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing the dropdown list get's called before the lifecycle methods are called.

Comment: I'm unable to determine any issues in your code, you could post the another question on StackOverflow, maybe someone else might know the issue.

Comment: You could try replacing `android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line` with `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`, but I doubt that that'll fix it.

Comment: To sum up, spinner works in popup, dropdown list dont work.

Comment: Cool, mark my answer as correct if you think it helped. :)

Comment: On a side note, where you able to find any documentation or reference that explicitly states that only spinners work in popup (and do you have any idea if this issue is device specific or agnostic)?